# How to do a prisoner role in discord.py 1.5.0?

Tags: discord.py

I've tried 3 times to do this code, my plan is removing all roles from an user, writing the roles in an `ctx.send()` to send a message with the old roles in the channel, after that, send a message that says the user was imprisoned and the reason and give the prisoner role.

> 'BabaYaga' is the adm's role; 'D 001' is the prisoner role

> Code 01:

```py
# Detentos 3
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role('BABAYAGA')
async def det(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, role =  discord.Guild.roles, *, reason = None):
    if member == None:
        await ctx.send('Say the user')
        return
    if reason == None:
        await ctx.send('Say the reason')
        return
    Roles = member.roles
    for _ in Roles:
        print(Roles)
        await client.remove_roles(member, *Roles)
        await member.add_role(ctx, member, role)
        await ctx.send(f'{member} was arrested for {reason}')
```

> Code 02:

```py
# Detentos 2
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role('BABAYAGA')
async def det(ctx, member: discord.Member, *,reason):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = 'D 001')
    await ctx.send(f'{member.roles}')
    for _ in member.roles:
        await member.remove_roles(member.top_role)
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji=self.tick)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f'{member} was arrested for {reason}')
```

> Code 03:

```py
# Detentos
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role('BABAYAGA')
async def det(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    if reason == None:
        await ctx.send('Say the reason!')
        return
    roles = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles) # member's roles
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = 'D 001') # Det's role
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji=self.tick)
    await member.edit(member.guild.roles)
    await ctx.send(f'{discord.Member} preso por {reason}')
    await ctx.send(f'cargos do {discord.Member}: {member.roles}')
```

> Code 04:

```py
# Detentos 
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role('BABAYAGA')
async def det(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason = None):
    if reason == None:
        await ctx.send('Say the reason! :angry: :angry:')
        return
    if member == None:
        await ctx.send('Say the user')
        return
    rolesserver = ['D 001', 'D 002', 'D 003', 'D 004', 'testers']
    await ctx.send(f'{member.roles}')
    for roles in rolesserver:
        await client.remove_roles(member, *roles)
    await ctx.send(f'<@{member.id}> was arrested for {reason}')
```

I don't know what is my error there. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What happens when you try to use that commands? And just to be clear, you want to remove all the roles of the member, then add him/her the prisoner role right?

Comment: Are you getting any errors at all? What is it doing that it shouldn't be? Just saying "it doesn't work" is not very helpful.

Comment: @Nurqm yes, alright. I'm tring to do a system that the member can't see the normal channels, only the jail. And, when I trid this commands, a lot of erros came.

Comment: @stijndcl sorry, it was my mistake, I forgot to save the erros to post here.

Comment: @RickDB you could've always ran your code again, if you say you get "a lot of errors" then it would really help to indentify & fix the problem a lot faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code snippets. Here's a correct way of doing it:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role('BABAYAGA')
async def det(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason):
    await ctx.send(f'Removed ", ".join([role.name for role in member.roles])')
    for role in member.roles:
        await member.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji=self.tick)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = 'D 001')
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f'{member} was arrested for {reason}')
```

Some advices:

- The [`get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get#discord.utils.get) method returns a single item from an iterable so writing `get(member.guild.roles)` won't work, you can just type `roles = member.guild.roles`
- You must set a variable in your `for` loops or else, you can't cycle through your member's roles, so your `for _ in member.roles` must become `for role in member.roles`.
- To have a nice message with all your member's roles, you can use the [`join`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) method combined with [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) (eg. `', '.join([role.name for role in member.roles])`)
- [`remove_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=remove%20roles#discord.Member.remove_roles) is a [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) method so you have to use it this way: `member.remove_roles(role)`

Comment: I had a problem. The PyShell shows this:
```
await ctx.send(f'Removed ', '.join([role.name for role in member.roles])')
TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: My bad, you have to replace `', '` to `", "` in ', '.join([role.name for role in member.roles])

Comment: Okay, I'll try it! @Mr_Spaar

Comment: now the PyShell showed it: `await ctx.send(f'Removed ', '.join([role.name for role in member.roles])')
TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: You need to put double quotation mark, as I said in my first comment

Comment: Ohhh, okay! @Mr_Spaar, I'll try it!

Comment: the `await ctx.send()` is running, the bot shows in the chat: `@everyoneRemoved , testadoresRemoved , D 004Removed , D 003Removed , D 002Removed , D 001`
But the PyShell showed another problem in the line:     `await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)`

Comment: could you edit your question with the full traceback ? There's no such line in the code I gave.

Comment: Ignoring exception in command det:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\v3\WICKPROJECT.py", line 92, in det
    await member.remove_roles(role)
  File "C:\Users\...\discord\member.py", line 685, in remove_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\...\discord\http.py", line 243, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role

Comment: Mr_Spaar This is the error.
Do you have discord? Send the error here is terrible.

Comment: I did the way you said:  `Ignoring exception in command det2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\Documents\Python\test\LIF BOT\v3\WICKPROJECT.py", line 92, in det2
    await ctx.send(f"Removed ", ".join([role.name for role in member.roles])")
TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: You only need to change the quotation marks from the `join` method, not the whole string: `f'Removed ", ".join([role.name for role in member.roles])'`. You have this error because they're all the same in your code.

Comment: okay, but: `raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role`. What it means?

Comment: Basically means that it wasn't able to find the correct role. In `discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = 'D 001')`, `name` must have the exact same value as your role name (It's case sensitive, so `D 001` is different from `d 001`). If it's already the same, I can't do much about that error :/. Could you delete your comments, they're all the same and are spamming the comment section ;)

Comment: Yep, know about the case sensitive, and I checked it!
Sorry for the spam! :/